# Get fragment layout from its id

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to change `fragments` inside my `activity` in an Android application.

I want to code a method which, based on `button`'s `id` changes the `fragment` inside my `view`, the problem is in the `myFragment` `class`

```
public static class myFragment extends Fragment {
        public RegisterFragment(int id){
                 this.id = id;
            }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            XmlResourceParser layout = getResources().getLayout(R.id.this.id); 
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

My problem as now is that `getResources().getLayout(R.id.some-random-id);` is givin error

```
Resource Id type is not valid
```

I'm using this `method` because I want to make a dynamic choose of the `fragment` `layout`, based, indeed, on its `id`.

I would like to use `android:id` to retrieve di `layout`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id ="@+id/register_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@color/background_blue" >
```

Am I using a bad approach?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

R.id will give you most of the views ID, but the layouts (activities, fragments..) are located in R.layout
You simply tried to access something that isn't located in R.id, hence not giving the good ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below code

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        return fragmentView
    }
```

Comment: yes, but I want to retrieve the layout id from the fragment id